# Prepositions, determiners and english grammar

Tags: grammaticality

How did you get _____ such a rare book? Please fill in the blank with the appropriate preposition.

I think it can either be 'by' or 'across' but I am not sure. Also I think that the 'get' there is incorrect but should be replaced by 'come'?

[image]

Comment: This is just an open-ended guessing game. My front-runner for a credible *[single]* "missing word" is ***given***. But ***me*** (or any other pronoun / name) might not be unreasonable. The only *preposition* that makes sense is ***into*** (what could have caused you to become *extremely interested* in this rare book?). Or ***in*** (if we suppose the addressee is actually *mentioned* in the book). But really it's just garbage from an incompetent test-setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe they left the word "**hold**" out of the example, and it wasn't caught when it was proofread. Or, possibly they could be asking you to complete with a phrasal verb "**get hold of**".

You could get "***hold* of**" a rare book.  Or,  as you mention, "***come by/come across***" a rare book. Perhaps you could use "**in**" (as a lone preposition) if you want to assume that the other person (the "you" in the example) was mentioned in the rare book.

I came across the link below about the phrasal verbs using "hold". It might help you with further support.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKdUDsBOXnc

Answer (score 1):

Neither "get by" nor "get across" work here. Unusually, the sentence makes sense in its current form. I'm unsure what you could add to make it make sense.

Another correct phrasing could be  "How did you come by ..." which means "acquire".

Edit - You could say "get at", which would be more asking how someone acquired access to the book, rather than the book itself.